# Duplicati Development when opening project in microsoft visual c# 2010 express get error The project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, git

I am opening a the Duplicati source code with i downloaded using Git.

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/duplicati/
```

I downloaded and installed there Visual C# 2010 Express and tried to open the project. With they recomened where https://code.google.com/p/duplicati/wiki/HowToBuild but when ever i try and build this project i get this error.

```
E:\duplicati\duplicati\Duplicati\GUI\Duplicati.GUI.MacTrayIcon\Duplicati.GUI.MacTrayIcon.csproj : error  : The project file 'E:\duplicati\duplicati\Duplicati\GUI\Duplicati.GUI.MacTrayIcon\Duplicati.GUI.MacTrayIcon.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.
```

Does anyone know what this error means?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: `Duplicati` - does that have anything to do with the illuminati?

Comment: It's the source code for backup software. http://www.duplicati.com/ (so i hope not)

Answer (score 0):

That's a MonoMac project.  Unload it; you presumably don't need a Mac build.

If you want to build it, you'll need to use MonoDevelop.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry but I'm going to ask a really stooped question. How do i go about Unloading it? (sorry)

Comment: Right-click the project, Unload project.  If the project type is not supported, it's probably already unloaded.

Comment: Haha so I downloaded the MonoDevelop (Xamarin Studio 4.0.13) http://monodevelop.com/Download and installed it know i get the error "This project type is not supported by Xamarin Studio on windows."